# Print the numbers from 1-100 skipping the numbers divisible by 3 & 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I want to print numbers from 1-100 skipping the numbers divisible by 3 & 5 and when I use the code-1 I'm not getting the correct output, I am getting full counting 1-100

```
#CODE1
i=1
a=1
while i<=100:
    if (a%3==0 and a%5==0) :
           a=a+1
    else:
        print(a)
        a=a+1
    i=i+1
```

but when I use the CODE-2 I am getting the desired result

```
#CODE2
i=1
a=1
while i<=100:
    if ((a%3 and a%5)==0) :
        a=a+1
    else:
        print(a)
        a=a+1
    i=i+1
```

*notice the fourth line of the code, why is wrong with the 1st code?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
a = 10

(a%3 == 0) and (a%5 == 0)  # False
(a%3 and a%5) == 0         # True
```

The first attempt gives `False` incorrectly because it needs *both* conditions to be satisfied; you need `or` instead. If you look carefully, some numbers (e.g. `15`) are excluded, coinciding with numbers which have both `3` and `5` as factors.

The second attempt is correct because if `a` is not divisible by *either* 3 or 5, the expression evaluates to `False`, and `0 == False` gives `True`. More idiomatic would be to write:

```
not (a%3 and a%5)
```

Answer (score 1):

a much cleaner answer at the level that he is looking at

```
a = 1

while a <= 100:

    if a%3 == 0 or a%5 ==0:
        a = a+1
    else:
        print(a)
        a = a+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The probelm is that 'and' should be changed to logic 'or' in Line5 of CODE#1. Current version 1 skips the numbers only when both conditions are met. You want to skip the numbers when either one or both of the conditions are met.

PS: I would like to suggest a faster and more efficient way of getting this result.

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.arange(1,101,1)
print('Original numbers \n', numbers)
print('Required numbers \n', numbers[(numbers%3!=0) & (numbers%5!=0)])
```

The answer from this will be:

```
Original numbers 
 [  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100]
Required numbers 
 [ 1  2  4  7  8 11 13 14 16 17 19 22 23 26 28 29 31 32 34 37 38 41 43 44
 46 47 49 52 53 56 58 59 61 62 64 67 68 71 73 74 76 77 79 82 83 86 88 89
 91 92 94 97 98]
```

Answer (score 1):

check this also it's working! 100%

```
def result(N):
           for num in range(N):
          if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
             print(str(num) + " ", end="")
          else:
             pass
    if __name__ == "__main__":
       N = 100
    
       result(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first program is incorrect because you on line 6-7 you increase the counter without checking to see if you need to print the number.

A cleaner way to write this could would be:

```
for counter in xrange(1, 101):
    if not ((counter % 5 == 0) or (counter % 3 == 0)):
        print (a)
```

Comment: If the first program "increase[s] the counter without checking to see if you need to print the number", the second program also does (the only difference between the two is *how* they check), yet that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=1

while 1<=n<=100:

    if((n%3 and n%5)==0) :
        False

    else:
        print(n)      
    n=n+1
```

Comment: The OP does not want a code that works but wants to know why the first code snippet does not work while the second does, which is already done in other answers. I don't see how your post is answering the question. Also it is always better to **add a few explanations** with the code so that your answer can be helpful to as many people as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you are using an *and* which is almost opposite to what you need, an *or* statement. I would advise you switch the **and** for an **or** statement.

```
#CODE
i=1
a=1
while i<=100:
    if (a%3==0 or a%5==0) :
           a=a+1
    else:
        print(a)
        a=a+1
    i=i+1
```

In the second code, you used a *nand* which is quite similar to an *or* in this situation and so works for the first parts of the data set. However in more complex code, this would give you a false negative to some checks and therefore I feel it should be avoided if not strictly needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 101):

   if i%3==0 and i%5==0:

    continue

   print(i)
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r = range(1,101,1)
for i in r:
      if i%3!=0 and i%5!=0:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1

while(i<=100):
if(i%3!=0 and i%5!=0):
    print(i)
i=i+1
```

**Try this one. It's simple clean and easy**